# Access Angular parent route data from children

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'd like to have the same data in children routes, but I can't find a way for accessing the parent route's data. That is, now I have:

```
{ path: 'parent-path', component: parentComponent, children: [
    { path: 'child1', component: child1Component,
      data: { sharedData: 'sharedData', child1Data: 'child1Data' }},
    { path: 'child2', component: child2Component,
      data: { sharedData: 'sharedData', child2Data: 'child2Data' }},
    { path: 'child3', component: child3Component,
      data: { sharedData: 'sharedData', child3Data: 'child3Data' }}          
]}
```

What I want is not have to repeat the same sharedData in all children. I tried this:

```
{ path: 'parent-path', data: { sharedData: 'sharedData'}, component: 
  parentComponent, children: [
    { path: 'child1', component: child1Component,
      data: { child1Data: 'child1Data' }},
    { path: 'child2', component: child2Component,
      data: { child2Data: 'child2Data' }},
    { path: 'child3', component: child3Component,
      data: { child3Data: 'child3Data' }}          
]}
```

But, by this way, in each component I only have his own data (childXData).

How could I access the parent route's data from the children?

Answer (score 4):

In child you can inject ActivatedRoute (route: ActivatedRoute) and then you can do: route.parent.snapshot.data['sharedData'] or without snapshot if you need observable.

Comment: How do you make route.parent.snapshot.data['sharedData'] available?

Comment: @techguy2000, `this.route` is an injected `ActivatedRoute` instance.